# Animacion sobrepuesta flutter

Tags: flutter, animated

Necesito hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo dos contenedores. **Contenedor1** siempre está fijo y es mas grande que el **contenedor2**

**Contenedor2** inicia oculto bajo el **contenedor1**. Al iniciar la `app`, este empieza un desplazamiento hacia la derecha mostrándose así.

Al terminar la animación esta se reversa pero a su vez se va mostrando sobre el contenedor1.

```
class UsernamePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UsernamePageState createState() => _UsernamePageState();
}

class _UsernamePageState extends State<UsernamePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller;
  late Animation<double> translate;
  

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 6000));

    translate = Tween(begin: -0.264, end: 0.02).animate(controller);
   

    controller.addListener(() {
      if (controller.status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        controller.reverse();
      }
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

[image: imagen ejemplo]

Comment: Hola, pero que es lo que deseas ?, recuerda revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: quiero hacer esa funcionalidad

Comment: ¿Qué es "esa funcionalidad"? Describiste qué estás obteniendo actualmente, pero no qué querés lograr. Como te han dicho, leé [ask], y pulsá en [edit] para dar más detalles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Básicamente podrías jugar un poco con los elementos dentro del `Stack` y alguna condicional.

Te dejo un ejemplo que hice para que te puedas guiar:

```dart
class PageWithAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageWithAnimation({super.key});

  @override
  State<PageWithAnimation> createState() => _PageWithAnimationState();
}

class _PageWithAnimationState extends State<PageWithAnimation>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  bool _forward = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final item1 = Container(
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      color: Colors.red,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: const Text(
        'C1',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _controller,
        builder: (context, _) {
          final item2 = Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(200 * _controller.value, 0.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
              color: Colors.purple,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text(
                'C2',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          );
          return Stack(
            children: [
              if (_forward) ...[
                item2,
                item1,
              ] else ...[
                item1,
                item2,
              ],
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          if (_forward) {
            _controller.reverse();
          } else {
            _controller.forward();
          }
          _forward = !_forward;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]